# Table columns set with some width

Tags: html, css

This is strange and I would even say that it isn't possible.

I have a table with 7 columns. I would like to have the

1. first column taking 10%
2. second+third+forth columns taking 45% of the width
3. fifth+sixth+seventh columns taking 45% of the width

is this possible?

I can do something like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      td {border:1px solid #000}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>very big text </td>
        <td>very big text never</td>
        <td>very big text never ending</td>
        <td>small</td>
        <td>small text</td>
        <td>small text foo</td>
      </tr>
      <!--<tr style="visibility:hidden"> to substitute -->
      <tr>
        <td style="width:10%"></td>
        <td colspan="3" style="width:45%"></td>
        <td colspan="3" style="width:45%"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

But this is so ugly.

Comment: is content dynamic...?? and do u need IE support too??

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/tG7sJ/ ?

Comment: Possibly. What did you try, and how did it work?

Answer (score 1):

`width` attribute on `td` or `th` is now deprecated as per HTML5

You could do it on CSS like this:

```
table td {
    width: 10%;
}
```

The partition of width measurement is now your job

UPDATE:

In your case, it seemed that 10% for first column, then 15% for the rest. Use something like this:

```
table td {
    width: 15%;
}

table td:first-child {
    width: 10% !important;
}
```

Comment: `first column taking 10% second+third+forth columns taking 45% of the width fifth+sixth+seventh columns taking 45% of the width` , I SEE ONLY ONE!! :)

Comment: yes you right, but he needs to set a group of three columns to special width, not each column to `15%`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible..See the `width` attribute for `Table columns`.

Answer (score 0):

how about this :

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 10%;"></td>
            <td style="width: 45%;">
                <table style="width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table style="width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: This is a 3-column table (with some inner tables meant to create a fake 7-column table), not 7-column table.

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela, yes you right, but he needs to set a group of three columns to special width

Answer (score 0):

**USE these links for Table columns set with some width :**

> http://www.w3.org/wiki/Styling_tables
>
> http://www.web-source.net/web_design_tips/setting_html_table_column_widths.htm#.UvnvHfmSw3I

***Width attribute on td or th is now deprecated as per HTML5***

**You could do it on CSS like this**:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
th, td {
  text-align: left; 
  vertical-align: top; 
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0.3em;
  caption-side: bottom;
}

th:first-child, td:first-child{ 
  width: 10%;
}

th.width-th, td.width-td{
  width: 45%;
}

caption {
  padding: 0.3em;
}
```

**HTML CODE :**

```
<table BORDER="2" CELLPADDING="2" CELLSPACING="2" WIDTH="100%">
<caption>Recent Major Volcanic Eruptions in the Pacific Northwest</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Volcano Name</th>
            <th class="width-th">Location</th>
            <th class="width-th">Last Major Eruption</th>
            <th class="width-th">Type of Eruption</th>
        <th class="width-th">Volcano Name</th>
            <th class="width-th">Location</th>
            <th class="width-th">Last Major Eruption</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Mt. Lassen</th>
            <td class="width-td">California</td>
            <td class="width-td">1914-17</td>
            <td class="width-td">Explosive Eruption</td>
        <th class="width-td">Mt. Lassen</th>
            <td class="width-td">California</td>
            <td class="width-td">1914-17</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Does not address the question. To begin with, the question refers to seven columns, not four.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems to be impossible to set column widths so that one column is 10% and the two groups of three columns is each 45%, with columns in each group taking their “natural” width within the available space (with widths allocated by the browser on the basis of the widh requirements of cells), which seems to be the question.

*If* the question is interpreted so that within the groups, individual columns widths can be set in any suitable way, say to equal widths, then the answer is almost trivial: assuming for definiteness that it’s the only table and that all cells are `td` elements, you could set

```
<style>
table { table-layout: fixed }
td { width: 15% }
td:first-child { width: 10% }
</style>
```

But if the allocation should be flexible within each group, there does not seem to be any way. Using `colgroup` does not help, since setting `width` on `colgroup` does not set the width of the group but of each column in it!

Using nested tables as outlined in @am1r_5h’s answer, you could have the desired allocation but for a different structure (a 3-column table containing two 3-column tables). Whether this addresses your needs depends on the context and purpose; it certainly introduces accessibility problems (and may make other styling more difficult).

If this is *really* important, you could use JavaScript to create a “dummy” table that contains all the data of the real table, organized into nested tables as mentioned, to get the widths of the columns of the inner tables, and to set the widths of the columns of the real table according to them. You would keep the “dummy” table invisible and delete it as soon as you have got the widths.